# Can't insert the new location to all keyframes

Tags: animation

So I am changed the hand location on animation. I need to copy the new hand location to all keyframes so the animation will be played on the hand with the new position.
I am pasting pose, choosing keyframes in action editor, pressing "I", choosing "Location" option and nothing happens. Position returns to the same as before.
How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean that for this hand there is a series of keyframes all along the timeline?

Comment: Yes. On imported animation keyframes are set all along the timeline.

Comment: so I suppose that you need to delete all the location tracks for the hand

Comment: Ok, think I found the solution. "Visual location" option in same menu works for me.